# adding an integer to values in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is my array

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to write a method in ruby that would add 5 to each value in the array. How can I do the same ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` like this :

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
arr.map {|n| n+5 }
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map.

**EDIT:** `map` will return a new array, if you want to modify this very array, use `map!` even if I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Ruby API Documentation for `Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

```
arr.map! {|i| i+5}
```